# How to design a python gui program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I currently have a working python code in command line. How can I convert this into a GUI program. I know how to design a GUI(make buttons,callback function, create text field, label widget...). My question is how should be the GUI connected to the existing program. 
*should I make a python file called gui.py and import this in the main program..
 ..or should it be in the other way...*
eg:

```
n = int(raw_input('enter an integer: '))

def fx(n):
    result = ''
    for i in xrange(1,11):
        result += "{} x {} = {}\n".format(i,n,i*n)
    return result

print fx(n)
```

the above program will print the multiplication table of an integer. How should be the gui program(with a entry box, button widget, text widget were o/p will be printed). should this program call the GUI code or should I include this code (**fx()** function) in the **GUI class**.

Comment: if it is a small UI then no need for making a separate file,else just import one of them into another & use widgets for printing stuff & taking user inputs

Comment: Hey, I forgot to loop the GUI in my previous comment, so I deleted it and replaced a proper link here. The pastebin link is: http://pastebin.com/TDZGA13p      But you may need to change xrange back to xrange as I changed it to range in order for it to work on Python 3.x, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the GUI is the user front-end, and because your function already exists, the easiest is to make GUI class to import the function. On event, the GUI would call the function and handle the display to the user.

In fact, it's exactly what you have done with a Command-Line Interface (CLI) in your example code :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer strongly depends on your choice of GUI-framework to use. For a small piece of code like the one you posted you probably may want to rely on "batteries included" tkinter. In this case I agree to the comment of shaktimaan to simply include the tkinter commands in your existing code. But you have many choices like PyQT, PySide, kivy... All these frameworks have possiblities to seperate programlogic from GUI-view-code, but have different ways to achieve this.

So read about these frameworks if you're not satisfied with tkinter and make a choice, then you can ask again how to do this seperation if you're not sure.